# How to transfer Spring Batch job from one POD to another POD after getting runtime exception or forcefully killing the running job

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, kubernetes-pod

My requirement is  :

I have to create a POC to show how can i shift all the jobs running from one POD to another POD in below scenarios -

- When the job running on POD 1 encounters runtime exception. I need to transfer rest of the workload to another Pod.
- if we forcefully kill job running on POD 1 or bring down the POD 1
- if CPU usage of a job running on POD goes more than 40% , I need to transfer load to another POD.

Is it possible to create one with Spring batch and Kubernets? I don't have any background in Kubernetes. Any guidance will help.

I have create spring batch application with multiple Steps. I am able to move from one Step to another based on job status but i want to replicate this in Kubernet , Pod.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your job as a developer to transfer jobs from one POD to another in those scenario. This is the job of Kubernetes.

All you need to do on the Spring Batch side is to ensure that job meta-data (ie restart meta-data) is correctly persisted and shared so that a job that fails on one POD can be restarted where it left-off on another POD.

As a developer, POD assignment/rescheduling should be transparent to you, which is one of the main reason you might want to deploy your batch jobs on Kubernetes (besides scalability, etc).

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud for the guidance.  One more point if you can help me understand is that a spring batch job can have two statuses: either COMPLETE or FAILED only so what status would it update in the table (batch_execution and batch_step_execution) when the job is abruptly shutdown or terminate?   When does the Spring batch actually update the status and exit code in batch_execution and step_execution?

Comment: The job could status could be in any of the BatchStatus enum values. If the job is abruptly shutdown, Spring Batch won't have a chance to update its status to FAILED or STOPPED, and won't be able to restart it. You can update its status to FAILED to restart it, or ABANDONED to discard it. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#aborting-a-job